# How to tail output of program started from crontab that prints to stdout?

Tags: command-line

I have a program, say

```
#!/bin/bash
while ( true ){
    echo 'hello'
    sleep 10
}
```

Which is started from the crontab like so

```
0 0 1 1 *
```

I can list this running process using a command like

```
ps aux | grep print.sh
```

Is there a way I can view the stdout of this script after it's been started from the crontab?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output to a file and then read it with `tail`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while ( true ){
    echo 'hello' >> $HOME/tmp/log
    sleep 10
}
```

Now you can view the output with `tail`.

```
tail -f $HOME/tmp/log
```